# page scroll is not happening appium java client

Tags: java, appium

I am doing automation mobile testing for my application .In login page after entering username & password,**keyboard** **pops up and blocks everything down in the screen** . So it's throws An element could not be located on the page using the given search parameters org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException:
To Enable scroll or screen touch i had tried many ways .

```js
1)
WebElement element1 = driver.findElement(MobileBy.AccessibilityId("btnLogin"));
      int x = element1.getLocation().getX();
      int y = element1.getLocation().getY();
    TouchAction action = new TouchAction((PerformsTouchActions) driver);
   action.press(x,y).moveTo(x,y-90).release().perform();
    
    2)
    WebElement element1 = driver.findElement(MobileBy.AccessibilityId("btnLogin"));
   ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);",element1);
    
    3)
    
     TouchAction action = new TouchAction((PerformsTouchActions) driver);
   WebElement element1 = driver.findElement(MobileBy.AccessibilityId("com.a.b:id/imageView"));
   WebElement element2 = driver.findElement(MobileBy.AccessibilityId("com.a.b:id/btnLogin"));
   action.press(element1).moveTo(element2).release();
    
    4)
    JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
   HashMap<String, String> scrollObject = new HashMap<String, String>();
   scrollObject.put("direction", "up");
   scrollObject.put("element", "btnLogin");
   js.executeScript("mobile: scroll", scrollObject);
    
    5)
    ((AndroidDriver) driver).context("NATIVE_APP");
   WebElement element = driver.findElementById("btnLogin");
   int x = element.getSize().getWidth();
    int xEnd = 0;
   int yStart = element.getSize().getHeight()/2;
   ((AndroidDriver) driver).swipe(x, yStart, xEnd, yStart, 500);
```

I am not able to resolve this issue .. can you please suggest me with some sample code to resolve this problem .

Answer (score 1):

To hide keyboard you can use following method driver.hideKeyboard() . This work with AppiumDriver.

After entering your username and password you can use this line of code :

driver.hidekeyboard();

Comment: i got that day .. For scroll i need more information .

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void swipeVertical(AppiumDriver driver, double startPercentage, double finalPercentage, double anchorPercentage, int duration) throws Exception {
    Dimension size = driver.manage().window().getSize();
    int anchor = (int) (size.width * anchorPercentage);
    int startPoint = (int) (size.height * startPercentage);
    int endPoint = (int) (size.height * finalPercentage);
    new TouchAction(driver).press(anchor, startPoint).waitAction(duration).moveTo(anchor, endPoint).release().perform();
}
```

Call the above method like:

For scroll Up: `swipeVertical((AppiumDriver)driver,0.9,0.1,0.5,3000);`

For scroll down: `swipeVertical((AppiumDriver)driver,0.1,0.9,0.5,3000);`